# In python, while loop i=+1 is an infinite loop, why?

Tags: loops, while-loop, increment, infinite

```py
i=7
while(i<=10):
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

Output : prints values from 7 to 10.

```py
i=7
while(i<=10):
    print(i)
    i=+1
```

But the above loop prints the values 1 and it is an infinite loop. Some of you please explain the different between the above two loops.

Comment: ```i=+1``` is the same as ```i=1```, which means that i is always less than 10, so it will print 1 forever

Answer (score 2):

```
# vv
i += 1  # i += 1
i =+ 1  # i = +1
# ^^
```

See the difference there? It hopefully becomes a little more obvious with extra spacing and the comments. The first *increments* `i` while the second just sets `i` to one.